# Where's the repository for the MonoDevelop ASP.NET MVC Support for the 2.1 trunk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop, moonlight

I'm using the openSUSE 11.1 VM with the latest MonoDevelop 2.1 trunk and Moonlight SDK.  I wanted to add ASP.NET MVC support but I can only find the 2.0.5 version in the repositories.  Is there another repository where this can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not yet. The only way is to build from source. I'll have to get round to making a package for my Build Service repository.

Sorry!

Comment: I've integrated the ASP.NET MVC addin into the main MD package and have pushed new source packages to the build service. It could be a few hours until they're build and in the repositories.